# autossh options to open a port through a jumpbox

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm connecting to a DB in a private subnet through a bastion host:

```
ssh -N -M -i ${PEM_FILE} -L 3306:${DB_HOST}:3306 ec2-user@${BASTION_PUBLIC_IP}
```

But the connection drops very quickly. Is there a way to use autossh in this scenario do maintain the connection alive?

Comment: can you quantify `very quickly` a bit  more? seconds, minutes? Can you get a connection through the port forward?

Comment: gave same answer on [dbaexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218307/telnet-to-mysql-which-timeout-is-used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered [-o ServerAliveInterval=30](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)?

I recommend making a `~/.ssh/config` host name for this server with all its configation options.